# need help with an odd json parsing issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-1.4

I have odd problems with parsing what I believe to be well-formed json returned from an ajax call (using jQuery 1.4.4). Oddly, on my dev server it works fine but fails online.

The data is returned from the ajax call as follows:

```
returnData = { "status": true, "data": { "error_return": false, "error_index": -1, "message_display": { "main_message": "hello", "name": "tommy tune the man", "mailed_to": "t@t.com", "subject": "I tried this", "subject_message": "you have a technical question or comment.", "test_me": "you have a technical question or comment." } } };
```

jsLint and jsonLint both validate this structure.

The error occurs when I try to access returnData.data

In the "fail" cases, I have removed the dataType from the jQuery.ajax options, thereby allowing the "best-guess" feature.  If I specify json, jQuery throws a parse error, claiming invalid json. I have tried all kinds of things (including the dreaded eval() and the jquery-2json plugin but no luck.  Even the jQ utility jQuery.parseJSON fails.

The problem occurs in both FF 3.6.13 and latest Safari / Chrome.

Question 1: does anyone why know the latest jQuery throws a parse error on this?

Question 2: when I try the following, I have success:

- var success = returnData.status;

BUT the following is undefined:

- var errorReturn = returnData.data.error_return.

Oddly, Firebug sees this as an object if I "paste" the object into the console, but within the script
1) returns "no child objects" in console.dir
2) BUT will display the object in console.log.

Ideas greatly appreciated

**UPDATE:
I discovered that the server was setting the Content type incorrectly.  In the server-side PHP that formats the JSON for return (created in this case in Drupal 6 (I had to hack the core-optional include "commons.inc"), I replaced the content type with 'application/json'. This now works. This problem has been corrected in Drupal 7.**

Comment: Using http://jsonviewer.stack.hu might helps to get a better insight into your data.

Answer (score 3):

If your quoted text is *actually* what's being returned, complete with the `return_data =` part, then it's invalid JSON.

If your ajax call looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "your_url",
    success: function(data) {

    }
});
```

...and within `success` you want to access the `status` value, your JSON should look like this:

```
{ "status": true, "data": { "error_return": false, "error_index": -1, "message_display": { "main_message": "hello", "name": "tommy tune the man", "mailed_to": "t@t.com", "subject": "I tried this", "subject_message": "you have a technical question or comment.", "test_me": "you have a technical question or comment." } } }
```

(Note, no `return_data =` at the beginning, no `;` at the end.)

...and your `success` function should look like this:

```
success: function(data) {
    if (data.status) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/eqafo3)

That example works with the latest Chrome, Firefox, Opera, ..., using the latest jQuery. Perhaps at some stage you were using a JSON parser that used `eval` under the covers. Your quoted example is valid JavaScript object literal notation as part of an assignment statement, but not valid JSON. Some "JSON" parsers actually use `eval` to parse JavaScript rather than JSON, that may have been your issue.

Comment: actually, json is a string and not a literal, so it needs to be `'{ "status": true, "data": { "error_return": false, "error_index": -1, "message_display": { "main_message": "hello", "name": "tommy tune the man", "mailed_to": "t@t.com", "subject": "I tried this", "subject_message": "you have a technical question or comment.", "test_me": "you have a technical question or comment." } } }'` otherwise it is an object literal

Comment: Or even `"{ \"status\": true, \"data\": { \"error_return\": false, \"error_index\": -1, \"message_display\": { \"main_message\": \"hello\", \"name\": \"tommy tune the man\", \"mailed_to\": \"t@t.com\", \"subject\": \"I tried this\", \"subject_message\": \"you have a technical question or comment.\", \"test_me\": \"you have a technical question or comment.\" } } }"` which would be how most serverside languages generate the serialization

Comment: @Martin: No. JSON is not a string. It's a textual data format. (And I didn't say it was a literal; I said that his quoted example contained a JavaScript literal.) You only need to put JSON text in quotes if you're specifying it in a string literal in a language. When it's a resource of its own (such as the body of an HTTP response). not only don't you want it in quotes, if you put it in quotes it will be invalid.

Comment: @T.J.: Since he is using jQuery to fetch it, I might have falsely assumed he wanted jQuery to parse it and deliver it in a usable way to his successhandler - unless he returns it as a string, that will not happen, but I could certainly have misinterpreted his intentions.

Comment: @Martin: My point is that you *don't* put it in quotes if you want jQuery to fetch it, parse it, and deliver it in a useful way to the `success` handler. See the [linked example](http://jsbin.com/eqafo3) and [the data it retrieves](http://jsbin.com/ugixi3). (Those are both links; stoopid SO not underlining links.) One almost *never* actually wraps JSON in quotes, unless one is mixing JSON-encoded data in program source code (either client- or server-side).

Comment: @T.J. you are of course right, my brain stopped working briefly, apologies :)

Comment: @Martin: LOL, we've all had that happen! Best,

Answer (score 0):

See my update as I have solved the problem. I apologize for not being more specific in my original post.  The variable `returnedData` is actually in the success callback (sorry about not specifying.)

For clarity, I am using the following with the jQ submit() function (in the click handler for this form submission):

```
var ajaxOptions = {   
  type: 'POST',  
  url: url,   
  dataType: "json",  
  beforeSubmit: checkInput,   
  success:
  evaluateResponse  
  }

  e.preventDefault();

  $(this).ajaxSubmit(contactOptions);
```

Where the success callback is:

```
  function
  evaluateContactResponse(returnData) {
  //and so on }
```

(Side-note: I was using the jQ form plugin until these failures occurred but moved to a different implementation since the form plugin failed silently.  I may now move this back since the form plugin is so elegant.)

The callback "evaluateResponse" is where the parsing takes place, and as I said, now works.

Thanks again... you are a smart guy
N

Comment: Glad you figured it out! Best,